# How to declare the model in config.xml?

Tags: magento-1.8

I'm stuck in the step "declare the model" before completing creating the module. Give me any guide to do? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It means, that you should declare model in config.xml like

```
<models>
            <photo>
                <class>Creare_Photo_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>photo_resource</resourceModel>
            </photo>
            <photo_resource>
                <class>Creare_Photo_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <photograph>
                        <table>photo_photograph</table>
                    </photograph>
                </entities>
            </photo_resource>
</models>
```

Took from http://www.creare.co.uk/magento-model-basics-the-complete-series

Comment: Mind that a resource model is often not needed. Additionally, mind that it is best practice to use `namespace_module` as an identifier, e.g. `creare_photo`.

Comment: Yes, you can work without resource model. For example, like in **app/code/community/Phoenix/Moneybookers/etc/config.xml**. Then node <resourceModel> is not needed. As for namespace your are absolutely right. For exmaple, in previous comment you can use descibed model by name **photo/photo** where photo after slash means class Creare_Photo_Model_Photo in your module etc.

Answer (score 0):

In this model declaration, you can use a template, then copy &paste, change model and table names.

In the above declaration, you can see 2 main TAGs:

- models: you must pay attention to 2 parts   and , which will be absolutely related. The rest, basically, is whole model of Module, which will be in folder app/code/local/MW/SimpleNews/Model
- resources: this is used to declare and use database connection for module, you just need copy&paste them for your other modules.

For full code, you can use thif source http://www.mage-world.com/blog/lesson-2-the-model-and-the-database.html

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the model in your config.xml file under app/code/local/yourpackagename/modulename/etc/config.xml

Add this code to declare models in the config.xml file

```
<global>
 ....
 <models>
   <class>Yourpackage_Yourmodulename_Model</class> 
 </models>
....
</global>
```